# An array with index [-1]

Tags: powershell

I have a function giving me some results of `Get-WinEvent` which works just fine. Using it as an input for another function and trying to iterate the array I notice, that the array is built like:

```
-1
   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
07.08.2019 01:14:23           1538 Information      The backup operation for the cluster configuration data completed successfully. The snapshot ID is '47cda23b-c446-43dc-9b5d-dfdbaca2be8c'.
```

Obviously I don't want to have the "-1" and "ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering".

How to get it right?

```
function Get-ClusterLogEntries {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [int] $server_id,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $clusterName
    )

    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "Server=xxxx\yyyy;Database=zzzz;Integrated Security=True"
    $conn.Open() | Out-Null
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("extern.xxxx", $conn)

    $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure

    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@server_id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::int) | Out-Null
    $cmd.Parameters['@server_id'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
    $cmd.Parameters['@server_id'].Value = $server_id #local server

    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@clusterName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 10) | Out-Null
    $cmd.Parameters['@clusterName'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
    $cmd.Parameters['@clusterName'].Value = $clusterName

    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@timeCreated", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime) | Out-Null
    $cmd.Parameters['@timeCreated'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output

    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $conn.Close()
    $conn.Dispose()

    $timeCreated = $cmd.Parameters["@timeCreated"].Value
    $startdatum = $timeCreated
    return [array]$clusterLogEntries = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{
        logname   = 'Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering/Operational';
        starttime = $startdatum
    }
}
```

and the consuming function:

```
function Write-ClusterLog {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [int] $server_id,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $computer,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $clusterName,
        [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)]
        [array] $clusterLogs
    )

    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "Server=xxxx;Database=yyyyy;Integrated Security=True"
    $conn.Open() | Out-Null
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("extern.zzzzzz", $conn)

    $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure

    foreach ($clusterLog in $clusterLogs) {
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@server_id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::int) | Out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@server_id'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@server_id'].Value = $server_id

        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@servername", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 10) | Out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@servername'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@servername'].Value = $computer #local server

        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@clustername", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 10) | Out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@clustername'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@clustername'].Value = $clusterName

        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@timecreated", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime) | Out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@timecreated'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@timecreated'].Value = $clusterLog.TimeCreated

        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@eventID", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::int) | Out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@eventID'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@eventID'].Value = $clusterLog.ID

        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@levelDisplayName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::varchar, 50) | Out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@levelDisplayName'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@levelDisplayName'].Value = $clusterLog.LevelDisplayName

        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@message", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 4000) | Out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@message'].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@message'].Value = $clusterLog.Message

        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    }
    $conn.Close()
    $conn.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Please show us the full function definition + how you call it

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

will [return an integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery#returns) indicating the number of rows affected by an INSERT or UPDATE operations - or for non-modifying operations, it'll return **-1**!

Change it to:

```
[void]$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
# or
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |Out-Null
```

Comment: Mathias, thanks, -1 is now gone, but still: while in the function Write-ClusterLog the Input Parameter $clusterLogs is an Array, in the loop: foreach($clusterLog in $clusterLogs)..the $clusterLog has the type: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.StartData  and $clusterLog.timecreated gives a null back...

Comment: Bacon Bits gave the Right answer.

Answer (score 2):

@MathiasR.Jessen's answer is correct for where the -1 came from.

The "ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering" is coming from the default output formatting for objects of the type that `Get-WinEvent` returns (`EventLogRecord`). It's the same reason you see "Directory: X:\foo" when you output Get-ChildItem.

To fix it, you need to select the fields rather than returning the entire object:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{
        logname   = 'Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering/Operational';
        starttime = $startdatum
} | Select-Object TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName, Message
```

If you need all the properties, you can specify `Select-Object *` instead, but you'll get a list output due to the number of properties to display.

If you need methods on the `EventLogRecord` class, then you can't do this because `Select-Object` with the `-Property` argument changes the object type to a `PSCustomObject`. You're unrolling the object from it's base class. If you *need* methods and you *need* to not show the provider name, you'd have to modify the `Types.ps1xml` file describing formatting for objects of type EventLogRecord. You almost certainly don't want to do this. See `Get-Help about_Types.ps1xml`.